# Infinite loop while trying to get the params of a member nested route

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Following the docs, I am defining a member route as follow (tried both in my debugging):

```
  resources :experiences do
    # member do
    #   post :request
    # end
    post 'request', on: :member   end
```

that shows properly when I check with `rails routes`

then, in my controller I define my action as such:

```
  def request
    puts 'Loaded experience'
    puts 'params'
    puts params[:id]
    # @experience = Experience.includes(:participants).find_by(params[:id])
    # p @experience
    # # check if new participant request is already in the participants
    # # TODO: to change to logged in user 'current_user' ?
    # @new_participant = User.find_by_id(params[:new_participant_id])
    # puts 'Loaded user'
    # p @new_participant

    # if @experience.participants.exists?(@new_participant)
    #   puts 'Participant exist'
    #   render json: { message: 'You are already a participant in this experience.' }, status: :conflict
    # else
    #   puts 'Adding participant'
    #   @experience_participant = @experience.experience_participants.new(participant: @new_participant, accepted: false)

    #   if @experience_participant.save
    #     render json: @experience_participant, status: :created
    #   else
    #     render json: @experience_participant.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    #   end
    # end
  end
```

I've commented out to debug. The problem arises with the `puts params[:id]` (or even just `puts params` for that matter)

It causes an infinite loop whenever I try to make an API call to the `experiences` controller. I can not even just `GET ../experiences`. The infinite loop will be triggered in that case as well.
The only thing I can do to be able to use my other routes is to comment out the `request` action method.

This is the error:

```
...
Loaded experience
params
Loaded experience
params
Loaded experience
params
Loaded experience
params

SystemStackError (stack level too deep):

app/controllers/experiences_controller.rb:56:in request'
app/controllers/experiences_controller.rb:58:in request'
app/controllers/experiences_controller.rb:58:in request'
app/controllers/experiences_controller.rb:58:in request'
app/controllers/experiences_controller.rb:58:in request'
app/controllers/experiences_controller.rb:58:in request'
app/controllers/experiences_controller.rb:58:in request'
app/controllers/experiences_controller.rb:58:in request'
app/controllers/experiences_controller.rb:58:in request'
....
```

I am not sure where to look for this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`params` is a method call. `puts params` is really `puts self.params()`.

[`request`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html) is a special method of your Controller used to fetch request parameters.

> The full request object is available via the request accessor and is primarily used to query for HTTP headers

So when you `puts params` that calls `request` to get the parameters, but it gets your custom method instead which calls `params` which calls `request` which calls `params`...

You'll have to name your method something less generic.

This is not well documented. These sorts of silent method name collisions are a consequence of Rails's design. An audit tool such as [`rubocop-rails`](https://docs.rubocop.org/rubocop-rails/) might catch these sorts of problems (and a lot more).

Comment: That's exactly what I was thinking when I was away. "Maybe `request` is a reserved word...". Well, that's it. 
Thank you for pointing that out!